# 12.10 nvidia driver issues

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, mode

After installing the nvidia drivers from the additional drivers tab of software sources, running nvidia-xconfig and dpkg-reconfigure xorg xorg-server xorg-server-core, the system still boots into low graphics mode.

It can be fixed by a restart of lightdm but this shouldn't be necessary, any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me on 12.10:

Make sure all three nvidia packages are installed:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings

(In case you want to be really sure; run install --reinstall). Also go for:

> dkms status

to double-check that the required modules for your current kernel were built
(it happened to me that I forgot to install the kernel headers after a kernel update; so dkms was not able to build the new modules automatically; leading to strange low resolutions on startup)

And you could run

> sudo nvidia-xconfig

asking nvidia to create its own /etc/X11/xorg.conf.